# Download Html in java returns different results

Tags: java, html, httpclient, inputstream, java.util.scanner

I am using code below to download a html file in java.
What I am doing here is that I am opening an inputstream to a website and after that I try to read the content and print number of lines in that html file (I am doing something useful in the real problem :p)
But every time that I run the code, the output is different.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(
                "URL");
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(instream, "UTF-8")));

                int count = 0;
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    count++;
                    sc.nextLine();
                }
                System.out.println(count);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
```

Can it be because the webpage that I am downloading is too big?

Comment: What URL is it pulling?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: use buffered reader , and if the prob exists try increasing the buffer size

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid I am already using a bufferedreader.